# PHP array to variable inside a link

Tags: php, arrays, variables, hyperlink

I'm using the code from this website: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/php-how-to-get-stock-quote-data-from-yahoo-finance-complete-code-and-tutorial/

```
$stock = "GOOG";
$objYahooStock->addFormat("sl1"); 
$objYahooStock->addStock($stock);

foreach( $objYahooStock->getQuotes() as $code => $stock) {
    $stock = $stock[1];
}
```

However, I can't use the variable `$stock` inside a link. If I try to display it on the page (`echo $stock;`) it's working. I'm able to see the stock price, but I'm not able to use the variable inside a link, see below.

```
http://example.com/example?text=' . $stock . '%20USD
```

I've also tried saving the stock price to a variable without the foreach loop.

```
$stock = "GOOG";
$price = $objYahooStock->getQuotes();
$stock = $price[$stock][1];
```

Same result here. I'm able to display the price but I can't use it inside a link.

Does anyone see the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your `a` link.

Comment: I'm using JS `window.open("http://example.com/example?text=' . $stock . '%20USD");` becuase I need to have it in a popup window. The variable `$stock` is working in my other examples. I'm also fetch stock price via Google Finance "Hidden API" and it's working. So the link should not be the issue, even if it seems that way.

Comment: Show the complete code of where you're code is going wrong.

Comment: can you check console log if you are getting any javascript error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to analyse output. Try `var_dump` and see the result.

In your case `$stock` have some character in string.
try below solution for **snl1d1t1cv** format:

```
$objYahooStock = new YahooStock;
$objYahooStock->addFormat("snl1d1t1cv");
$objYahooStock->addStock("GOOG");

$price = $objYahooStock->getQuotes();
$stock = "GOOG";
$stock = $price[$stock][1];

var_dump($price);
echo '<script>window.open("http://example.com/example?text=' . str_replace('"','',$stock) . '%20USD");</script>'
```

This solution opening a new window at my machine

Edit:
for the format **sl1** below solution will work:

```
$objYahooStock = new YahooStock;

$objYahooStock->addFormat("sl1");

$objYahooStock->addStock("GOOG");


$price = $objYahooStock->getQuotes();
$stock = "GOOG";
echo $stock = $price[$stock][1];

var_dump($price);
echo '<script>window.open("http://example.com/example?text=' . str_replace('\n','',trim($stock)) . '%20USD");</script>'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, `str_replace('\n','',trim($stock))` was the solution.

Comment: I solved it with `$stock = str_replace('\n','',trim($price[$stock][1]));`. can't change variable `$stock` in the link since I'm using the same structure else where.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your full code, it's difficult to see what you are doing, but `http://example.com/example?text=' . $stock . '%20USD` looks as if this is HTML and not PHP?

Depending on your approach ...

PHP: `echo 'http://example.com/example?text=' . $stock . '%20USD';`

or;

HTML: `http://example.com/example?text=<?=$stock?>%20USD`

EDIT: I see you are using JavaScript from your comment, so use the HTML example above.